# How can I see the system status during boot?

Tags: macos, mac, startup

I would like to monitor the messages generated when I boot my Mac, similar to what you on a *nix box. Is there key-combo to press/hold that will let me do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to press <kbd>cmd</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> upon startup to see the boot output. Press this right after the *chime*.

If you want to make that permanent, you should probably do something along the lines of:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="-v"
```

To *undo* the above:

```
sudo nvram boot-args=
```

in the Terminal. (/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app)

**note**: I haven’t tested the above commands, but I’m sure a google query will help you there if you want to make it permanent.

Comment: I can hardly wait to try this.  I hate staring at the apple on boot.

Comment: Why? What's wrong with it?

Comment: As a Linux user, I am used to reading log messages during startup. They are far more interesting than a boring progress bar. Now that I've bought my first iMac, I'm pleased to have startup log messages on it too.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see the boot messages after the boot occurred, log in and run `sudo dmesg` in Terminal.app.