# Is there any way to see what OS X is doing when it's booting up when no chime is played?

Tags: terminal, time-machine, startup

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I see the system status during boot?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/how-can-i-see-the-system-status-during-boot)

I have had the hard drive in my iMac replaced and now I'm trying to restore it from my TimeMachine back up. I thought the TimeMachine back up was corrupt but maybe I'm just not patient enough, or I'm misunderstanding the restore process.

I'm able to restore successfully, but on reboot the machine shows me the white screen with the Apple logo and the spinner. I can hear some occasional sounds from the hard drive in the machine. It's been at this screen for a good hour now. The occasional hard drive sounds make me wonder if it's doing and fsck or similar operation on the drive before the system boots.

**No chime has been played yet by the system. So the usual Cmd-V and Cmd-S solutions to see what it's doing or to boot to single user mode aren't working for me.**

Is there any way to *see* what OS X is doing at boot time? I'm thinking something akin to the terminal window that modern Linux distros like CentOS can show you at boot time. The ones that let you see the step-by-step boot messages as they happen.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I see the system status during boot?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/how-can-i-see-the-system-status-during-boot) (Yup, I just voted to close my own question...that's a first for me)

Comment: I suppose this is slightly different from the other question in that I don't get a chime.

Comment: You can delete your own question I think, rather than vote to close.

Comment: @mankoff: I think I might leave it. In my case my machine won't chime so the Cmd-V solution doesn't work.

Comment: Per [“Intel-based Mac: Startup sequence and error codes, symbols”](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2674), the startup chime happens before the Apple logo is displayed. Thus you should be able to do a verbose boot by pressing and holding ⌘V before the chime sounds (such key combinations are effective only if you press (and hold) them before the first Apple logo (the one without the spinning gear)). [“ Mac OS X: Gray screen appears during startup”](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS2570) covers what to do when the system will not boot up to at least the blue screen.

Comment: I realize the docs say I should hear a chime, but I do not. I got the apple logo, no chime. I'd film it for you, but I've since fixed the machine by doing a clean OS X install and then restoring from TimeMachine during the first login.

Answer (score 1):

See Apple support document [Mac OS X: How to start up in single-user or verbose mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1492)

Answer (score 1):

The system chimes after running the POST, but before loading the OS.  If it's not making it to the chime, it's failing the POST and there's no activity to see, no matter what keys you press.

Answer (score 0):

When you turn it on, hold <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd> for few seconds.

Comment: Why the downvote? His edit about cmd+v occurred after I posted.