# How to debug Mac that hangs during boot?

Tags: macos

I would like to see what is going on behind boot screen (similar to Linux where one can see what is going on).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On intel macs with non volatile ram, enable [verbose mode at boot](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/4235/5472) (which shows the progress up to the point where the UI starts).

```
sudo nvram boot-args=“-v”
```

Then your next start should show you details. To remove this, reset the NVRAM, delete the key `sudo nvram -d boot-args` or blank the arguments `sudo nvram boot-args=`

There is a shortcut key command-v as well.

- https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255

On Apple Silicon, you would need to inspect the recovery logs or perhaps generate a recovery diagnostics file.

- https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/macos-recovery-a-mac-apple-silicon-mchl82829c17/mac

Comment: Even if the UI isn't working you might be able to SSH onto the box and check /var/log/system.log for faults ..